# How to efficiently check that a matrix is symmetric with respect to the secondary diagonal

Tags: matrix, symmetric

I know how to check for the main diagonal symmetry.

```
for (line=0;line<size;line++)
    for (column=0;column<size;column++)
        if (matrix[line][column]!=matrix[column][line])
            return false;
return true;
```

How do i replace the condition inside the if to check the symmetry with respect to the secondary diagonal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
The if becomes:

```
if (matrix[line][column]!=matrix[size-column-1][size-line-1])
    return false;
```